# What should be implemented by WebElementProxy in order to pass it to Actions.moveToElement(WebElement)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` there is the method named `moveToElement(WebElement target);`

I have a class `WebElementProxy`, which implements `WebElement`:

```java
public class WebElementProxy implements WebElement {
    private WebElement el;
    public WebElementProxy(WebElement el) {
        this.el = el;
    }
    /* Implement methods from WebElement, delegating directly to el field. */
}
```

When I try to call `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(webElementProxy)` I get the following error:

```java
class mypackage$WebElementProxy cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Locatable
```

So, I added Locatable to the interfaces of WebElementProxy:

```java
public class WebElementProxy implements WebElement, Locatable {
    private WebElement el;
    public WebElementProxy(WebElement el) {
        this.el = el;
    }
    /* Implement methods from WebElement and Locatable, delegating directly to el field. */
}
```

Now when I call `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(webElementProxy)` I get the following error:

```java
invalid argument
from invalid argument: 'origin' must be either a string or a dictionary
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:639)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:595)
    at the place in my project where I called actions.movetoElement()
```

At this point, I don't know what else I need to implement in order to make this method call work correctly.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe check here?: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html  What functionality are you trying to add/override here?

Answer (score 0):

It got solved for me, in a similar case (with Serenity's WebElementFacade), by passing the underlying element directly: `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(el)`.